# Style child component from parent component using styled-components

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a parent component and a child component. I import child component into parent and use it there. Below is the child component.

```
import styled from "styled-components";

const HeaderContainer = styled.h1``;
const Header = () => <HeaderContainer>This is Header</HeaderContainer>;
export default Header;
```

As you can see it is a simple component all it does it render text.

The parent component is below.

```
import "./styles.css";
import Header from "./header";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Main = styled.div`
  ${Header} {
    background-color: "red";
  }
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Main className="App">
      <Header />
    </Main>
  );
}
```

I am importing Header and using it inside JSX. What I want is to style Header component from parent component. I tried below styles using styled-components but it does not work somehow.

```
const Main = styled.div`
  ${Header} {
    background-color: "red";
  }
`;
```

Here is the codesandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-brown-w3bbs?file=/src/App.js:0-277

How can I make this work or if you have a better idea then please share.

Comment: _"index.js:27 Header is not a styled component and cannot be referred to via component selector. See https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components for more details."_

Comment: @jonrsharpe I just updated the codesandbox. I forgot to make it styled component.

Comment: But you're not referring to `HeaderContainer`, you're referring to `Header`, so the same warning is still shown. Read the console messages, and the docs the link to.

Comment: @jonrsharpe In the docs styles for both components are in the same file so we can refer to that component. In my case Header component is in a different file. It has a HeadeContainer styles which I am using it inside JSX. But I am export the component as Header. Which I import in parent component as Header not as HeaderContainer. So I cannot refer to it as HeaderContainer because it is undefined. I can refer to it as Header only.

Comment: I'm not saying you _should_ refer to HeaderContainer, necessarily, just that Header, the component you're _actually_ referring to, **is not a styled component**. That's what the warning tells you, and presumably why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any global class names or selecting DOM elements which are both obvious bad practices. Instead, just use "styled" on the child component **inside its parent**. So, e.g., in your case:

```
import Header from "./header";
import styled from "styled-components";

const StyledHeader = styled(Header)`
    background-color: "red";
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Main className="App">
      <StyledHeader />
    </Main>
  );
}
```

Also it's important to **notice that:** Some CSS-in-JS tools will require you to manually add a className prop inside the child component's props in order for this to work. So, e.g., your Header component must become:

```js
const Header = ({ className }) => <HeaderContainer className={className}>This is Header</HeaderContainer>;
```

You don't need to pass this prop yourself from the parent component, your CSS-in-JS tool will pass this className automatically.

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully I'm following what you want to do but in your Main styles you could just target the h1 for the header?

```
const Main = styled.div`
    h1 {
        background-color: red;
    }
`;
```

Or if you didn't want to target all H1's then add a className to your header, I've added a few ways to do this here: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-stallman-bdwfk?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I just updated the codesandbox the header.js file and converted that header into styled component. Now your solution does not work.

Comment: You need to add styles to a styled component rather than react component. I've updated my sandbox with a few possible solutions.

Comment: Both your solutions are bad practices.

Answer (score -1):

In your code, the part where you tried to style the header, it was wrong. Instead what you can and should try is:

1. inline styles:

   ```
   import "./styles.css";
   import Header from "./header";
   import styled from "styled-components";

   export default function App() {
     return (
       <Main className="App">
         <Header style={{background-color: "red"}}/>
       </Main>
     );
   }
   ```
2. External CSS

   You can give a class name to your elements inside the components and style them in the parent file like the following

   *The css file, let's name it style.css*

   ```
   .header-heading {
     font-size: 4rem;
     color: "red";
   }
   ```

   *The child component*

   ```
   const Header = function () {
     return (
       <h1 className="header-heading">This is the heading</h1>
     );
   }

   export default Header;
   ```

   Then you can import both of them in the parent file and you'll see that the child component is styled now.

   *The parent component*

   ```
   import React from "react";
   import Header from "./Header";

   import "./style.css";

   const App = function () {
     <>
       <h1>Below is the h1 component rendered</h1>
       <Header />
     </>
   }
   ```